# Disabling or overriding some http headers on seam applications?

Tags: http, jsf, http-headers, seam

I want to  disable x-powered and some other headers on my seam application how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove x-powered add in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To add a custom header in pages.xml add

```
<header name="CustomHeader">value</header>
```

es.

```
<page view-id="*">
<header name="CustomHeader">value</header>
...
</page>
```